# How to create a link to the DATE when ARTICLES were posted, and list all the articles posted on the same DATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to list the month, day and year in which each one of my articles were created. Until this point everything works fine.

I need to GROUP my articles according to the DAY they were created. For example:

---

- **October 4th, 2017** ( this must be a link that, once cliked, leads me to a page 
                     with a collection of ALL the articles created on that day 
                     ).

  ```
                Besides making "October 4th, 2017" a link to all the 
                articles, I also need to list those same articles titles 
                below "October 4th, 2017" on the initial page.
  ```

  - **First Article** ( link to that individual article )
  - **Second Article** ( link to that individual article )
  - **Third Article** ( link to that individual article )
  - And so on ...

---

My code looks hacky, but until now everything works EXCEPT for the fact that the "October 4th, 2017" link doesn't lead me to a page where I can see all the articles, but it gives me a weird URL that only shows the very first article. It looks like this:

---

### website.com/articles.34%2F38%2F39%2F40%2F41%2F42

Here's my code:

```
  articles_controller.rb

  def listarticles

    @articles = Article.order(date: :desc) 
    @article_days = @articles.group_by { |t| t.date.beginning_of_day }

  end
```

---

```
listarticles.html.erb

<% @article_days.each do |day, articles| %>

   <%= link_to day.strftime('%d''%B' '%Y'), articles_path(articles) %>

   <% articles.each do |article| %>

       <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>

   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is this:

```
articles_path(articles)
```

You've passed an array of articles to the path, which Rails converts to their ids. So this translates to something like:

```
/articles.34/38/39/40/41/42
```

This gets encoded into what you get there ( "/" replaced by %2F)

I'm not sure how you got the first article from this. But usually the part after the dot denotes the format, as you can see if you rake your routes:

```
articles  GET  /articles(.:format)   articles#index
```

In order for the `#index` to only show the list you want, you need to send it as a query string:

```
articles_path(ids: articles.map(&:id).join(","))
```

This will give you

```
/articles?ids=34,38,39,40,41,42
```

Then in your controller, you need something like this:

```
def index
  ids = params[:ids].split(",") if params[:ids]
  @articles = Article.where(id: ids) if ids
  @articles ||= Article.all
end
```